# What is the difference between regular electro-mechanical relay and an electro-mechanical relay with optocoupler?

Tags: relay

I've got a simple question. I was looking for a single channel relay module but see that they come in two types, [regular electromechanical relay](https://www.electronicscomp.com/1-channel-5v-relay-module-without-optocoupler?gclid=Cj0KCQjw--2aBhD5ARIsALiRlwCv4UveZGMmsKjH_S6h0AaXp4I9OD_mFNr8TmSS9dzhmij6MT80DPgaAlEwEALw_wcB) and [electromechanical relay with optocoupler](https://www.electronicscomp.com/1-channel-5v-relay-module?gclid=Cj0KCQjw--2aBhD5ARIsALiRlwDXoUgcA0wMpSlCf1jctBQU0_4kxJB2zBDS2z91TjV0j4pgh1I2racaAsnNEALw_wcB). What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Relays don't come in two types - it's just those boards that do. Your links are to a supplier's website, for small PCB assemblies rather than actual relays. The manufacturer's documentation and your own research are your way forward. As this is a shopping question about a sub-assembly, I'm voting to close, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TonyM Your point is understood but the question is useful as a general example. He has provided example devices but any devices with similar features would suffice. You MAY wish to remove your close vote BUT I have absolutely no problem if you disagree with my comment and wish to leave your close vote in place.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I will leave my vote and maintain my view. These are not commonplace sub-assemblies, like a PSU or Arduino I/O module - distinctly enough, I think, to be just a shopping question.

Comment: Please provide schematics and data sheet links of those two boards. In my experience, a relay that also uses an opto-coupler is a marketing scam to make you pay for something you probably (999/1000) don't need,

Comment: @TonyM this is not a shopping question this is a knowledge question (and of course all knowledge in applied sciences is commercially targeted, no shame in that.) I am not asking which relay module would suit my application best (I would decide that myself based on the knowledge I receive here), you would notice I have not even mentioned my application. I am just asking what is the difference between the two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use an opto-coupler?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337039/why-use-an-opto-coupler)

Comment: The difference is that one is a single part (a relay) and the other is two parts (a relay and an optocoupler).

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you mean by "it's not a knowledge question". It's no more than reading the technical documentation for the parts, which is a fundamental of electronics development and what I politely posted as "The manufacturer's documentation and your own research are your way forward". I'm very much for giving technical support to advance the work of OPs, that's why I'm here. But these really are very simple assemblies for anyone to research, as some answers and comments attest to.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Your linked question is useful, but also misleading in this case. In the specific example asked about, and in a range of devices currently on the market, the optocoupley is providing only limited isolation. This is because the ground is (stupidly) common between the opto negative input and the relay driver proper. This provide some protection against 5V driver failure if the ground is "stiff". And against breakover from the driven load **IF** the load shares the same ground (unlikely) and the ground is (again) "stiff". ie an opto isolator only answer would mislead the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have linked to specific examples the answer is "generic".
One relay has no isolation between signal line and relay drive electronics.
The other has partial optical isoation on the input.

In both your examples the actual rerlay is electromechanical.
In the non opto-isolated version the input signal drives a transistor which operates the relay.  If the transistor went short circuit, or if the relay output voltage somehow connected to its coil, then the voltages involved would be connected to the input line - probably causing damage.

The optically isolated relay uses an optocoupler driven by the input signal. The output of the optocoupler drives a transistor which drives the relay.
The opto coupler provides SOME isolation. However, as the only connections provided are In VCC and Ground, the input signal must share a common ground with the relay coil and VCC. This means that the opto isolation is not very robust. Such a device could be imprived by cutting the ground track from the isolator input to common ground and providing a new signal-ground. This would allow superior isolation.

Without isolation all subsystems involved must share a common ground. eg Relay module and Arduino.  The opto-isolator when used with no common ground works by passing the signal using a light generator (usually an LED) and a light detector.

---

WARNING:  Relays of the type shown, sourced at low cost from (usually) Asian suppliers, and especially of the brand shown in your example, are labelled as rated at 250 VAC and 10A BUT are not safe for use at that currentv rating. They MAY be suitable for use at lower currents at 230 VAC. Or not. (I have operated these at approaching 10A with consequent failure.)

Quality relays which meet the ratings shown are available. These  could be soldered into boards like these, but they are substantially more costly.

Comment: Thanks, it brings some clarity to my query, but also your comment about making a separate ground for signal is meaningful to me in another way. I once tried (being an amateur) to signal the relay module from an arduino but power it externally (not from arduino). Of course it didn't work as the signal was never finding a ground in the Arduino. Next time for such an objective maybe I'll try to give up the modules and design something myself.

Comment: @DribbleNibble Witout isolation all subsystems involved must share a common ground. eg Relay module and Arduino.  The opto-isolator when used with no common ground works by passing the signal using light and a light detector.

Answer (score 5):

Based on those two links you gave, the other module just has an optocoupler which can be included in the marketing material to indicate it's more fancy.

The difference is not in the relay itself, it's a difference of the module which includes the circuit on PCB.

Any product sold should come with enough info such as a manual with technical data on the input interface.
Don't buy a module unless you know what you are doing.

The optocoupler is not really used for isolation, because regardless of the optocoupler, the module has one ground and one supply pin, in addition to the input, so the relay drive and logic circuit must share a common reference.

Basically, the difference is if the MCU is connected to drive the transistor base or optocoupler input diode.